# Switch-like function for questionnaire grading

Tags: r, for-loop, switch-statement

I'd done a serious PHP/JS coding recently, and I kind-of lost my R muscle. While this problem can be easily tackled within PHP/JS, what is the most efficient way of solving this one: I have to grade a questionnaire, and I have following scenario:

```
raw    t
5      0
6      2
7-9    3
10-12  4
15-20  5
```

if `x` equals to, or is within range given in `raw`, value in according row in `t` should be returned. Of course, this can be done with `for` loop, or `switch`, but just imagine very lengthy set of value ranges in `raw`. How would you tackle this one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We seem to be missing a part of the example because there in no mention of "x"

```
dat <- read.table(textConnection("raw    t
 5      0
 6      2
 7-9    3
 10-12  4
 15-20  5"), header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dat$bot <- as.numeric( sapply( sapply(dat$raw, strsplit, "-"), "[", 1 ))
get.t <- function(x) findInterval(x, dat$bot)
 get.t(8)
#[1] 3
> dat$t[get.t(6)]
[1] 2
> dat$t[get.t(5)]
[1] 0
```

Comment: S-U-B-L-I-M-E! Thanks with sugar on top! =)

Comment: `findInterval` and `match` are very handy in the quest to achieve loop-free code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing on `findInterval`. I wasn't aware of such a function... O_o

Comment: +1 for findInterval. That function is sexy, and fast as hell.

Comment: Salma Hayek is sexy, `findInterval` is just useful. And fast. As hell. =)

Comment: Shouldn't the get.t function be like that: `get.t <- function(x) dat$t[findInterval(x, dat$bot)]`. Otherwise `get.t(5)` yields 1.

Comment: @learnr. Excellent point The `get.t` function returns an index should be used to pull values from the second column.

Answer (score 2):

I would simply use an indexing scheme kind of like what Corbin alluded to, but since he didn't provide an example, here's a simple one:

```
m <- cbind(c(5:12,15:20),
           rep(c(0,2,3,4,5),times = c(1,1,3,3,6)))

m[m[,1] == 11,2]
[1] 4
```

Comment: Your answer is indeed simple, but not scalable for multiple `raw` columns, which is common scenario in questionnaire grading. +1 for simplicity, but @DWin d-wins this one. =)

Comment: @aL3xa I agree; I was mainly aiming to provide an example for folks who find this question in the future, but are less concerned with scaling.

Comment: Yepp, I forgot to stress the fact that non-R solutions are not welcome. =)

Answer (score 0):

Note: very similar to Simone's answer as I started typing this a bit back.  Has a note at the end though.  The indexing approach I give is essentially Simone's answer.

There will have to be a loop involved somewhere.

The pseudo code of what I would do is something like:

```
score = blah

for each raw => t
    break raw into rMin -> rMax
    if(rMin <= score and rMax >= score)
        return t
```

It avoids having to loop over each number between rMin and rMax (which is what I'm assuming you meant), but without some kind of indexing, that is the best you're going to get.

Note: if you have a ton of calls to this, and indexing would actually be worth your while, the easiest type of indexing would just be a hash map of score -> t entries.

Basically you would parse your example data into something like:

```
index[5] = 0
index[6] = 2
index[7] = 3
index[8] = 3
index[9] = 3
```

You would need to carefully weigh if building the index would be more time consuming than just looping over the ranges.

Note: the indexing approach is actually what Simone said.